# Asp mvc 3 noobie: Why is the code-first method not building my DB on sql server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am an ASP MVC 3 noobie who has done a few tutorials. Now I'm trying to build a site. All of the tutorials on the microsoft website emphasize the code-first approach: you define your model with code and then create a datacontext and then the entity framework creates/manages the DB based on your code.

I set up an Employees class and a DataBaseContext class that inherits from DbContext. I added a connection string to Web.config connection string that successfully links DataBaseContext **to an already existing empty DB on SQL server.** *EDIT= That was the problem. See my answer below*

But when I try to run the Employees controller created thru scaffolding, I get this error

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Employees'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of...
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Employees'.
```

I followed this post [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Categories'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374482/sqlexception-0x80131904-invalid-object-name-dbo-categories) and realized that if I create an employees table on the DB, this excpetion goes away (I get a new one saying that the column names are invalid).

But I thought the whole point of MVC 3 is that the framework will make the DB for you based on the code.

Maybe I need a line of code in the Global.asax Application_start() to create the database? Here is my application_start method:

```
Sub Application_Start()
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
```

Here is the code for Employee:

```
Public Class Employee

    Property EmployeeID As Integer
    Property First As String
    Property Last As String
    Property StartDate As DateTime
    Property VacationHours As Integer
    Property DateOfBirth As DateTime 'in case two employees have the same name

End Class
```

Here is the code for the DB context:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class DatabaseContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Employee As DbSet(Of Employee)
    Public Property AnnualLeave As DbSet(Of AnnualLeave)

End Class
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your model classes and dbcontext class you have for employee. It sounds like you are trying to use entity framework code-first, correct?

Comment: @davidisawesome I posted the additional code

Comment: I don't believe you need anything in the app_start. Let me take a look for a little bit and I will try and figure it out. Is this a brand new project, or something that you already have messed around with?

Comment: Brand new project. It could be an issue with sql server permissions or something. I was getting a createTable not allowed error, but managed to fix that one.

Comment: Using the localdb for the connection string or a seperate one you have set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default EF uses `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TContext>` database initializer. Accordingly to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=vs.103%29):

> An implementation of `IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>` that will delete, recreate, and optionally re-seed the database with data only if the model has changed since the database was created. This is achieved by writing a hash of the store model to the database when it is created and then comparing that hash with one generated from the current model.

Since the database was created manually, EF can't find the hash and decides do not perform any further initialization logic.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look [into this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374482/sqlexception-0x80131904-invalid-object-name-dbo-categories), same question successfully answered already.
Or it can be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015458/problem-with-sqlexception-0x80131904-invalid-object-name-dbo-tablename) (also resolved successfully)
Answer to your problem is most likely one of the two.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Does the name you're specifying for your connection string match the name of your database context?

For example:

**Context**

```
var myDbContext = new MyDbContext();
```

**Connection string**

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="YOUR.CONNECTION.STRING" providerName="System.Data.SqlServer" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. The connection string name and db context name match, so it's got to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this post I wrote about DbContext with MVC works for you: [Code-First](http://www.nerdlythings.com/Post/Custom-MVC-Blog-Part-2---Entity-Framework-Code-First?id=7)

Not a lot to be done to get this to work, but there are a few things that are easily missed that will cause a bunch of head aches.

hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the link. I didn't see anything in there that would explain why the db is not building. maybe i need to add a line to build the db in application start?

Comment: From what I learned about it, if you have your DbContext set up correctly and it is in the connection string, the first time it tries to access a view that needs that table, it should build it out for you automatically. Have you checked the actual database to see if it is getting generated?

Answer (score 0):

I had already created a database with that name on SQL server. Once I deleted the existing database, the code first framework created the tables for me like it was supposed to. It seems like if the database already exists, the framework won't set up the tables for you. It wants to create the whole DB from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You were using `AdventureWorks Database`?

It has it's own schema assigned to the employees table. `HumanResources.Employees` and not the default `dbo.Employees`.

Even though I've identified the problem, I don't know the solution to using the database as configured with the `HumanResources` schema.

Anybody know?