# SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'PlanningRow'

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, sql-server-express

I have an asp.NET MVC 3 application which uses nHibernate and SQL Server Standard Edition. The production-environment works fine, and was developed by someone else.

I'm trying to set up a test-environment on my local PC, and restored a backup from the live Db to my local SQL Express. Changed the connection strings, and got the sessionfactory running. (I'm still learning the different aspects of asp.NET MVC, so I'm not totally confident I've checked everything that needs to be checked).

Unfortunately, now when the index.cshtml is loaded, it fails with the mentioned error (SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'PlanningRow'). It fails on the line:

```
planningRows = Planner.GetCurrentSession().QueryOver<PlanningRow>().List();
```

I've seen similar problems posted on StackOverflow and elsewhere, and I know the error means it can't find the table- but the Db and the table are on my local SQL Express. But it is very well possible the database or table is not in the right schema or the schema does not exist. Unfortunately, I don't know what that actually means, let alone how to fix it, and I can't really find hints about how to do this.

(f.i. [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Categories'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374482/sqlexception-0x80131904-invalid-object-name-dbo-categories) gives some interesting options- especially option 2- but no way how to check or fix this).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: could it be a typo ?? your notes indicate the error references "PlanningRow", however the code snippet uses "PlanningRows"

Comment: Nice catch :-) But no, that was a typo in the post: I've changed the actual names since it's not my own code/website...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015458/problem-with-sqlexception-0x80131904-invalid-object-name-dbo-tablename

Comment: Seen it, didn't help me understand how to check if my table is in the wrong schema or how to change this

Answer (score 1):

- double check the connection string points to the correct database
- enable SQL-logging with "NHibernate.Sql" in DEBUG mode
- check the mapped schema in PlanningRow mapping and default schema in hibernate.cfg file or config code

Comment: Found the answer with a collegae, but your answer is on the right track: if I added the schema in the mapping XML it worked (I didn't know how or why to do this but a collegae helped me out). Still strange, because the live environment does NOT need this directive :-/ Anyway, it worked and I could continue debugging.

Comment: I'd created a new database but created my table in the wrong database..!